# Functions corresponding to highest weight vectors

Tags: rt.representation-theory

For the action of $GL(n) × GL(m)$ on $C[Mat(n × m)]$, the polynomial functions on $n × m$ matrices, what are the functions which are the highest weight vectors with respect to both $GL(n)$ and $GL(m)$?